# How to know keystore type

Tags: java, keystore

I'm in the process of WS security. In my application user may give JKS file or PK12 file. 
I load the keystore file using the following code,

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
ks.load(inStream, "pass".toCharArray());
```

It is throwing `Invalid keystore format`

- So is there any way to find if the file is JKS or PK12 or any other else?
- Should I get it from the user what kind of file he is using?

I'm new to this, correct me if my understanding is wrong. I apology for wasting your time, if this is duplicate.

Comment: You need the user to tell you, or to adopt some naming convention like .jks/.p12 that tells you. Otherwise you're just going to have to try both and see which works.

Comment: OK. I saw there where many keystore type available. I have to try all of them?

Comment: All the ones you want to support, obviously. Hard to see why you need to ask.